# Webkit CSS filter blur not working in Safari on Windows OS

Tags: html, css, safari

Basically I am using the CSS3 filter and using blur(); to create a blur effect on my background. It works in every browser except for Safari on Windows 7 OS. The code I am using is:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(15px);
-moz-filter: blur(15px);
filter: blur(15px);
```

Is there something I am missing as to why it is not working in Safari?

Comment: We'd need to see it in action. Can you make a JSFiddle or provide us with a link? That said, it only works on elements...not background images...

Comment: What version of Safari are you use?

Comment: The code I am using is http://jsfiddle.net/T4Q8t/ and I am using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the current Safari version on Windows is some way behind the current Safari version for Mac.

On Windows, the current Safari version is only 5.1, compared with 6.0 and 7.0 on Mac.

The bad news for you is that Safari 5.1 does not support the `filter` style.

There is no way around this; it simply isn't supported, and won't be until Safari gets an update on Windows.

The only good news is that there aren't that many people using Safari on Windows, so this issue shouldn't affect too many of your users.

You can see more about the browser support for this feature on CanIUse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: Bit late to the party, and almost 3 years at that; but, I've just stumbled across this as a Win10 user - further research has thrown up the consensus that Apple aren't supporting further updates Safari for Windows. Boo-hiss Apple!